# Bootstrap Loading after custom style in Angular6 in production mode

Tags: angular, angular6

In a very strange situation, Angular6 application after building in production mode --prod, when it loads, custom styles are getting supersedes by bootstrap. At the other end the same is working fine without --prod mode at the local system.

FYI, here is the code snippet of angular.json file:

```
"styles": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "src/styles.css", "src/assets/css/new-age.css"]
```

Here is the screenshot of the difference at my localhost and online app published with code --prod

[--prod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtQ7x.png)
[simple load ng serve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGCIt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the way, Angular priotise stylesheets having any import like we do import Google Fonts.

Make a separate css file for these imports and then include it in angular.json will serve the purpose.

Please see below link:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9475

Answer (score 0):

try to import it at the beginning of your globale **"style.scss"** file

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```